# c++, Value entered using cin against scanf

Tags: c++, scanf, cin

Why do we use & in scanf, but not in cin? What does exactly happen behind the scenes? For example :

```
scanf("%d", &num);
cin >> num;
```

Comment: C++ references vs. C and pointers?

Comment: `scanf` modifies the value of your integer, so it has to be passed a pointer as the second argument.

Comment: @ForceBru: What do you think `cin >> num` does?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, just the same, but without pointers, I presume.

Comment: @ForceBru: That's right. So, the OP is asking _how_ without pointers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I'm not so familiar with C++, that's why I've explained why we need `&` in C (in case OP didn't know).

Answer (score 5):

`scanf` is from the C standard library<sup>1</sup>. In C, there is no such thing as a reference. Therefore you need to pass around pointers to accomplish equivalent results.

`std::cin` is from the C++ standard library. In C++, there **is** such a thing as a reference. Therefore you can write `std::cin >> num` and everything's fine.

---

<sup>1</sup> If you use `scanf` in C++, you *should* always use `std::scanf` from `cstdio`, which technically is from the C++ standard library, although originating from the C standard library.